# Connecting to bitbucket repository from jenkins server

Tags: git, ssh, jenkins, bitbucket

At moment I'm trying to create connection from jenkins to my bitbucket repository, using the git plugin that I've installed in jenkins.

When I enter to the repository URL, I get the following message notification shown in the figure:

"Failed to connect to repository : Command "ls-remote -h git@bitbucket.org:safe2school-ondemand/s2s-android-padres.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly"

[image: Trying connect to bitbucket repo from jenkins through git]

I've install jenkins on apache tomcat container, which is located in a path /srv/apache-tomcat

In the system I have a  root ssh-key and I add this key to bitbucket.
I appreciate your support :)

Comment: did you set up the ssh keys for the Jenkins user? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13890500/why-i-couldnt-add-the-git-url-to-my-jenkins

Comment: Note that credentials support is built-in to the git plugin now. The screenshot shows that you've chosen no credentials for this repo.

Comment: Christopher, what credentials may I have add, In this field .. are the username and password of my bitbucket account.  I don't think so..

Comment: If you don't want to go the user password root, I did have a similar issue that I solved and posted an answer for in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34420362/jenkins-get-code-from-bitbucket-with-ssh/34889442#34889442  The TLDR; presuming your keys are all set up correctly, try removing the ".git" from the end of the repo url.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can try with user-password authentication credential, this is the alternative way that this plugin gives us.

1. Click 'Add' button.

[image]

2. Select "User with password" in Kind input.
3. Add bitbucket account credential.

[image]

4. Enter bitbucket repo url using 'https' protocol.

[image]

Finally, the absence of errors (like red messages under repo url input) means that the process had success.

Comment: Clear info. Thanks!

Comment: Is there any additional step needed when the 2 factor authentication is enabled on Bit bucket account?

Comment: @Techroshni I am not sure but I guess jenkins will show up the right form when you setup 2fa as a kind of credential, anyway, if you tried it please add an update to this answer 

Comment: I changed the kind input to "SSH Username with private key" instead of using "User with Password" and utilized private key to set up authentication for my repo.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @geoom answer, 2FA users can use "[app passwords](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/app-passwords-828781300.html)" for the credentials

> App passwords are substitute passwords for a user account which you
>   can use for scripts and integrating tools to avoid putting your real
>   password into configuration files.
>
> App passwords are designed to be used for a single purpose with
>   limited permissions, so they don't require two-step verification
>   (2SV). This means app passwords can be used by users with 2SV make API
>   calls to their Bitbucket account, and to integrate Bitbucket with
>   other tools like Sourcetree and Bamboo.

Comment: Do these passwords disappear if that user is removed from bitbucket (ie if they leave a company)

Comment: @AdamHughes just chiming in here because I have the same issue at my company. We use the Jenkins bitbucket plugin to poll for SCM changes using my credentials (and app password). We are looking to substitute this for a generic SSH key belonging to Jenkins, but it doesn't seem that this is possible.

I found the following resources that you might find useful, and it is clear that BitBucket expects integrations to be built using named accounts as opposed to service accounts:

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/how-do-you-create-a-service-account/qaq-p/883530

Comment: (cont.)

And this bitbucket ticket:

https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-15600?focusedCommentId=2644907&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-2644907

Comment: Thanks Justin I will check these out