# Jenkins - Get code from BitBucket with SSH

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh, bitbucket, ssh-keys

I Created a private key and added the public key to my keys on bitbucket just like explained in this [tutorial](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html)

I'm trying to add the private key to Jenkins under Credentials menu but it just keep saying:

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe -c core.askpass=true ls-remote -h git@bitbucket.org:bla/blabla.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: Permission denied (publickey). 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What am i doing wrong withing Jenkins?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Jenkins.  Then in the configuration help of my job I spotted this

> For a remote URL to a super-project, the ending of the URL determines whether a bare or non-bare repository is assumed:
>
> - If the remote URL ends with /.git, a non-bare repository is assumed.
> - If the remote URL does NOT end with /.git, a bare repository is assumed.

Now I'm not sure why the documentation the /.git but this led me to try my repo url without the .git suffix, since a repo in bitbucket is bare.

so in your case I would try setting the repo url to:

```
git@bitbucket.org:bla/blabla
```

Note the ".git" has been removed.